# Places SDK IOS output language

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I'm building an app on ios based on the user's current place and I'm using Google Places SDK for ios to find the current place of the user. 
The problem is that I would like to get the adress in English and the SDK is providing it to me in the system language. 
Is there a way to specify the output language ?

For example : 
On an iPhone in french i'll get country Italie instead of Italy.

Comment: I believe the feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828434 is what you are looking for. Feel free to star it.

Comment: Thanks, I hope they will fix that as soon as possible ;)